# BLE Scan stops after discovering few devices

Tags: javascript, bluetooth, bluetooth-lowenergy, bluez, raspberry-pi4

After running the following code for the **first time** that is from one of the examples given [here](https://github.com/noble/noble/blob/master/examples/advertisement-discovery.js) on my Raspberry Pi 4, it works fine and finds many devices. But when I rerun the scanning function is broken and only finds few devices:

```
noble.on('stateChange', function(state) {
  if (state === 'poweredOn') {
    noble.startScanning();
  } else {
    noble.stopScanning();
  }
});

noble.on('discover', function(peripheral) {
  console.log('peripheral discovered (' + peripheral.id +
              ' with address <' + peripheral.address +  ', ' + peripheral.addressType + '>,' +
              ' connectable ' + peripheral.connectable + ',' +
              ' RSSI ' + peripheral.rssi + ':');
  console.log('\thello my local name is:');
  console.log('\t\t' + peripheral.advertisement.localName);
  console.log('\tcan I interest you in any of the following advertised services:');
  console.log('\t\t' + JSON.stringify(peripheral.advertisement.serviceUuids));

  var serviceData = peripheral.advertisement.serviceData;
  if (serviceData && serviceData.length) {
    console.log('\there is my service data:');
    for (var i in serviceData) {
      console.log('\t\t' + JSON.stringify(serviceData[i].uuid) + ': ' + JSON.stringify(serviceData[i].data.toString('hex')));
    }
  }
  if (peripheral.advertisement.manufacturerData) {
    console.log('\there is my manufacturer data:');
    console.log('\t\t' + JSON.stringify(peripheral.advertisement.manufacturerData.toString('hex')));
  }
  if (peripheral.advertisement.txPowerLevel !== undefined) {
    console.log('\tmy TX power level is:');
    console.log('\t\t' + peripheral.advertisement.txPowerLevel);
  }

  console.log();
});
```

If I reset the device, the issue disappear. If I scan via `bluetoothctl` then `scan on`, there is no issue at all. I can **scan on and off** as I want. So my guess is that the issue is related to [noble.js](https://github.com/abandonware/noble)

Here is the output of `sudo btmon` where scanning stops.[image: sudo btmon output]

Here is the image of how the `scan on` hangs.[image: scan on hanging]

The **BlueZ** version is **5.50**.

Comment: @ukBaz Then it is related to `hci` API. How can I exactly locate the issue? `Command disallowed` error did not lead me anywhere.

Comment: @ukBaz I am manually stopping the discovery, as it runs forever. I am not getting any notification as well. If I rescan, the problem occurs. Then, it does not matter where I do the scanning, both `noble.js` and `bluetoothctl scan on` only find few (1 or 2) devices. I guess, I need to deep dive into `noble.js` to understand what is breaking the scanning.

Comment: OK, I may have misunderstood the issue you were having. Is it that you need to allow duplicates?  https://github.com/noble/noble/blob/c4cd18a7a429bb832f6c4ca793be3faf9af884e9/README.md#start-scanning

Comment: @ukBaz Sorry if the issue is not clear in the question. The issue is that, the `scan` function is not working as expected after a few runs,  if we run it via `noble.js`. Normally, the `scan` finds many devices and it is continuous.  However, if we `scan` several times via `noble.js`, it is broken. Only find 1 and 2 devices, and it stops discovering. Then in `btmon`, I get `command disallowed` which did not lead me anywhere.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue was I was just exiting the script without stopping the scanning while **duplicates** set to `false`. Hence, when I rerun, only a few new devices were found.